# Zend_Json_Exception Decoding failed: Syntax error some time in Magento (All versions)

Tags: module, custom, magento-2.0, exception, rest-api

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Zend_Json_Exception): **Decoding failed: Syntax error**
>   Exception #0 (Zend_Json_Exception): **Decoding failed: Syntax error#0** /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Json/Decoder.php(20): Zend_Json::decode('') #1 var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Json/Helper/Data.php(58): Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder->decode(false)

In my `custom mdoule` I am creating a slider by fetching data form API.

> IN `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php`

```
<?php
namespace Custommodule\ReviewRating\Block;

class HomehorizontalWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_helper;
protected $jsonHelper;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = [],
    \Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    $this->_helper = $helper;
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
}

  .................

 public function get_reviews_data( $url ){
        $dataResponse = $this->getDataFromApi($url);
        return $dataResponse['data']['reviews'];
 }

    public function getDataFromApi($url)
    {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        $decodedData = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($data);

        return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $decodedData : false;

    }
```

> IN `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/homehorizontalwidget.phtml`

```
    $url = "http://website.com/api?url";

       $reviewsData = $this->get_reviews_data( $url );
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r( $reviewsData );
       echo "</pre>";
?>
```

---

**Update :** I chnaged few things as below ( No idea is it the perfect way or not)

Below code is from Magento 1.X version

> 1) Return 0 if empty

public function getDataFromApi($url)
    {

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = ( string ) $data;
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        if( empty( $data )){ // retrun 0 if empty
            return 0;
        } else {
            return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
        }
```

}

> 2)  check on phtml page is array is empty or not

```
   $reviewsData = $this->get_reviews_data( $url );
      $reviewsImages = $this->get_reviews_images( $url );
      $totalRatingCount = $this->get_avg_reviews_count( $url );
      $avgRating = $this->get_avg_reviews_rating( $url );


if( empty( $totalRatingCount) && empty( $avgRating ) && empty( $reviewsData ) && empty( $reviewsImages) ){
        return;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using below code
In Magento V 2.x

```
/**
     * fetch data from api
     * @param  string $api_url pass API url
     * @return array return decoded API data to view to render on templates
     */
    public function getDataFromApi($psy_api_url)
    {
        sleep(1);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        $data     = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = (string) $data;

        if ($httpcode == 200) {
            try {
                if ($data) {
                    $decodedData = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($data, true);
                    return ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) ? $decodedData : false;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // do nothing
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

In Magento 1.x

```
/**
     * fetch data from api
     * @param  string $api_url pass API url
     * @return array       return decoded API data to view to render on templates
     */

    public function getDataFromApi($api_url)
    {
        sleep(1);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        $data     = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = (string) $data;

        if ($httpcode == 200) {
            try {
                if ($data) {
                    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // do nothing
                 return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code.

> app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php line number 657

replace

```
public function jsonDecode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType = Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY)
{
    return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
}
```

with

```
public function jsonDecode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType = Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY)
{
    if (empty($encodedValue) || $encodedValue == NULL ) {
        return Zend_Json::decode('{}', $objectDecodeType);
    } else {
        return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue while Persistent Shopping Cart enabled from admin. I fixed issue using above code

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your function:

```
public function getDataFromApi($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = (string) $data;
    $decodedData = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($data, true);
    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $decodedData : false;
}
```

Comment: 1) Zend_Json_Exception it comes some time not always. 2 ) your code gives me 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Json.php on line 76

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Json.php on line 76

Comment: Update ans pls check now

Comment: Its not working , same  issues